# Prevent Unauthorised traffic - Azure static website

Tags: azure, security

I have a staging website that is hosted as an Azure Static Website (Blob Storage). I am looking at setting this up with a non default Url and would like to lock this site down to prevent unauthorised access, mainly to prevent indexing on Google etc.

I have tried setting up a firewall on the storage account but this seems to only hide the error page as I can still access the root url but anything else returns me a 404.

Im sure there is a solution to this problem but I can't seem to find anything online.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why preventing google indexing? Could you please give a little more context?

Comment: So I have been running a staging/preprod web application in Azure. I am ready now to setup a Production environment and therefore will be buying my domain name ready to go live to the world. I would like to set my staging site up at staging.domain.com and then have my prod site at domain.com. I dont want my staging site to be found and indexed by search engines so i was thinking of adding a login page when you first hit the site. I could also just lock the site down to my personal Ip address but cannot get this to work.

Comment: have you check this kind of article? https://michaelsoolee.com/prevent-google-index/? Not sure if it will work for static webiste ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Thomas - I'm not sure that I trust this method as I'm sure somewhere along the way this has burnt a team I was on. I don't want to have to deal with the hassle of trying to get Google to remove the site.

Comment: Have you seen this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54349118/restrict-access-to-static-website-hosted-on-azure-storage-to-intended-users

Comment: So after searching around I have finally come up with a solution. After looking at functions, ip whitelists behind the CDN I ended up going for a soft login page. Although I did have success with the function (running as a proxy) the simplest solution will work just fine. For my staging site I simply check the existence of a record in local storage, if it doesnt exist I route the user to a soft log in page, I call it soft as its just client side but it will be enough to stop Google and other bots from crawling my site.... Simple.